# Callback method after for delayed job - render js alert

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an app with delayed job. I want to use the callback once the action finish (after, success or finish) and inform the user on the client side. I have something like this:

```
class ScannerJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(links, count = 0)
    links do |url|
       broadcast_it(url.to_s, count +=1)
    end
    after
  end

  def after
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :js => "alert('Congratulations');" }
    end
  end
```

I got something like this: unterminated string meets end. I found this source telling that it is impossible to do it.

What is the best way to handle this and why can't I simply call the respond js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it's impossible to do it. Let's find out why.
I am positive that you how normal `HTTP` request cycle work.
In a traditional way `Client` asks a `Server` to fullfill his request. whether it's querying about a data or it's sending a data to store on server. Server handle the client's request and send the response to client. After the server has full filled the client's request there is no way server is gonna communicate to client unless client asks/request again. So basically clients requests server and server responds to that request and wait for the next request.

No let's go with the delayed job stuff.
You know why we add delayed job in our project. There might be some performance hungry or time taking tasks which will delay the user response if we handle them synchronously . i-e

Assume I want to send an email to 100 people separately on user's request and each email takes 5 seconds to deliver. So it will take 500 seconds (around 9 minutes) to deliver all of those.

We cannot do it in a synchronous way as it will be a bad experience for the user. User request will timeout or even if does not timeout then user will treat it as non responding request and leave the site.

So what we do we process these email sending tasks as background. And whenever user request to send an email to 100 people we send the response back to user at once and tell them the success message. and we ask delayed job to handle this task in background.

```
class MyController  < ApplicationController
def process_heavy_requestion
   EmailerSender.delay.send_email_in_backgroun(params) #We are delegating email sending task to delayed job. And we assume it will be done.
   render text: "Email sent Successfully"
end
end
```

In this action we responded user with a message. and sending email in background.

So if we map it to the above discussion then Server has responded the client by success message. 
So if we wanna send a response to user afterwords then it's not possible. unless user asks us again.

So now let's solve your problem.

You want to inform use about the actual progress of background task then here is a way.
Whenever task is executed in background you can set a flag in user table/or any other table. What is the status of that task. Even you can add another column in your custom worker.

Before calling background task you need to change the value of that column to 'pending'. In delayed job worker you will set the value of that column accordingly i-e (Failed or Done)

So basically the task output will be stored somewhere in database or even you can store it in user session.

So whenever user asks to handle that request you will handle taks in background and with javascript add a script in response which will check the result of that task after fixed time i-e (5 seconds) . So with javascript you will send the request to server after every `X` seconds what is the status of my previous task . If server responds that it's been done then you show user the success message or if fail then you show the user the error message.

I hope it will clear your confusion

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. I eventually solved it by using ActionCable. I tried the after(job) method but didn't figure out how it works.